# IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor using robot framework with Python

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I am trying to run the following Python 2.7.10 code on Win7:

```
from robot import run

run("Login.robot", variable=['USERNAME:testuser@fakemail.com'])
```

Login.robot is a very simple robot framework test that opens a browser window, loads our log in page, enters in a username and password, then confirms the user has logged in. I have tested it by running it from the command line with pybot and the test suite runs correctly. But trying to run the test suite from this script generates

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmdunn\Desktop\test_user_data.py", line 4, in <module>
run("Login.robot", variable=['USERNAME:testuser@fakemail.com'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\run.py", line 471, in run
return RobotFramework().execute(*datasources, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 83, in execute
return self._execute(list(arguments), options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 96, in _execute
details, rc=FRAMEWORK_ERROR)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 110, in _report_error
self._logger.error(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\loggerhelper.py", line 59, in error
self.write(msg, 'ERROR')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\loggerhelper.py", line 62, in write
self.message(Message(message, level, html))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\logger.py", line 109, in message
logger.message(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 66, in message
self._writer.error(msg.message, msg.level, clear=self._running_test)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 142, in error
self._highlight('[ ', level, ' ] ' + message, error=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 158, in _highlight
self._write(before, newline=False, error=error)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 154, in _write
stream.flush()
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Any suggestions? I've tried using an absolute path to the robot file, single quotes, double quotes, referencing via an open file object, referencing via a closed file object. Thanks!

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem. Your code ran exactly as posted for me on a linux box.

Comment: Well, at least now I know it's a Windows problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it was due to using IDLE, which prevented robot framework from writing to the console. My script runs when started from the Windows command line.

Answer (score 0):

Open a file handle and call robot.run method inside while handle is open.
I hope this will solve your issue.

```
mydir = os.path.join('c:/','....')
os.makedirs(mydir)    
with open('mydir', 'w') as stdout_file:
            k = run("Login.robot", 
                     variable=['USERNAME:testuser@fakemail.com'],
                     stdout=stdout_file)
```